# Structural modeling in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I must solve an exercise. 8-BIT AND, OR, NAND, XOR using ALU, BASYS3 BOARD. I must use structural modeling style but I don't know how so, I tried in my way. Here is the code:

```
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity ALU is
Port (
A: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
B: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
OPCODE: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0);
C: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0)
);
end ALU;

architecture Behavioral of ALU is

Signal s: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);

begin
C<=s;

process(A,B,OPCODE)
begin
    if(OPCODE="00") then -- OR
       s(0)<=A(0) or B(0);
       s(1)<=A(1) or B(1);
       s(2)<=A(2) or B(2);
       s(3)<=A(3) or B(3);
       s(4)<=A(4) or B(4);
       s(5)<=A(5) or B(5);
       s(6)<=A(6) or B(6);
       s(7)<=A(7) or B(7);
    else
        if(OPCODE="01") then -- AND
            s(0)<=A(0) and B(0);
            s(1)<=A(1) and B(1);
            s(2)<=A(2) and B(2);
            s(3)<=A(3) and B(3);
            s(4)<=A(4) and B(4);
            s(5)<=A(5) and B(5);
            s(6)<=A(6) and B(6);
            s(7)<=A(7) and B(7);
        else
            if(OPCODE="10") then -- NAND
                s(0)<=A(0) nand B(0);
                s(1)<=A(1) nand B(1);
                s(2)<=A(2) nand B(2);
                s(3)<=A(3) nand B(3);
                s(4)<=A(4) nand B(4);
                s(5)<=A(5) nand B(5);
                s(6)<=A(6) nand B(6);
                s(7)<=A(7) nand B(7);
            else
                if(OPCODE="11") then -- XOR
                    s(0)<=A(0) xor B(0);
                    s(1)<=A(1) xor B(1);
                    s(2)<=A(2) xor B(2);
                    s(3)<=A(3) xor B(3);
                    s(4)<=A(4) xor B(4);
                    s(5)<=A(5) xor B(5);
                    s(6)<=A(6) xor B(6);
                    s(7)<=A(7) xor B(7);
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;
    end if;
end process;

end Behavioral;
```

and here is the constrains file

```
## Switches
set_property PACKAGE_PIN V17 [get_ports {A[0]}]                 
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {A[0]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN V16 [get_ports {A[1]}]                 
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {A[1]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN W16 [get_ports {A[2]}]                 
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {A[2]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN W17 [get_ports {A[3]}]                 
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {A[3]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN W15 [get_ports {A[4]}]                 
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {A[4]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN V15 [get_ports {A[5]}]                 
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {A[5]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN W14 [get_ports {A[6]}]                 
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {A[6]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN W13 [get_ports {A[7]}]                 
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {A[7]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN V2 [get_ports {B[0]}]                  
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {B[0]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN T3 [get_ports {B[1]}]                  
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {B[1]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN T2 [get_ports {B[2]}]                  
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {B[2]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN R3 [get_ports {B[3]}]                  
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {B[3]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN W2 [get_ports {B[4]}]                  
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {B[4]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN U1 [get_ports {B[5]}]                  
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {B[5]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN T1 [get_ports {B[6]}]                  
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {B[6]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN R2 [get_ports {B[7]}]                  
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {B[7]}]


## LEDs
set_property PACKAGE_PIN U16 [get_ports {C[0]}]                 
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {C[0]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN E19 [get_ports {C[1]}]                 
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {C[1]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN U19 [get_ports {C[2]}]                 
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {C[2]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN V19 [get_ports {C[3]}]                 
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {C[3]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN W18 [get_ports {C[4]}]                 
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {C[4]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN U15 [get_ports {C[5]}]                 
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {C[5]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN U14 [get_ports {C[6]}]                 
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {C[6]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN V14 [get_ports {C[7]}]                 
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {C[7]}]


##Buttons
set_property PACKAGE_PIN W19 [get_ports OPCODE[1]]                      
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports OPCODE[1]] 
set_property PACKAGE_PIN T17 [get_ports OPCODE[0]]                      
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports OPCODE[0]]
```

This code is working, but as I said, I must make it in structural modeling style and I don't know how.

EDIT:

Figure:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpRrR.png

Specs:

- A and B are 8 bits operands
- the operations will be established through the OPCODE ( entry port )
- list of operations: logical operations on bits: OR, AND, NAND, XOR

The results will be assigned to port C and will be visualized by the LEDs on the development board.

Comment: Structural modeling consists of building a design hierarchy instead of a flat design using block statements (usually external blocks represented by an entity and architecture pair instantiated as components). Show  your homework assignment directions. The inference here would be than you're instantiating individual logic gates.  What's not clear is what set of components (2 input gates?).

Comment: Ok, so I add my homework assignment directions.

Comment: The issue here is that your reading audience is unaware of what course you're taking and the objectives of the assignment. Likely no one here has sat through the same course or so much as seen lecture notes. You can help, including by describing as best you can what you don't understand and provide pointers to course references. You're question is still lacking a specifc problem to be addressed in an answer.

Comment: Everywhere you have a logical operator can be replaced by a 2 input gate performing the same function. There would be additional signals for inputs to a 4:1 multiplexer (done structurally) selecting which of the sets of operations are output on C. The multiplexer can be implemented structurally in it's own design hierarchy. Component instantiations are concurrent statements and don't occur in process statements.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so I tried to make it by my own and I think it'll work. Now I need to try this on a basys3 board.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

package componente is
-- componente
    component AND2 is
    port(   Aand, Band : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 7 DOWNTO 0 );
            Cand : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 7 DOWNTO 0 )
            );
    end component AND2; 

    component OR2 is
        port(   Aor, Bor : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 7 DOWNTO 0 );
                Cor : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 7 DOWNTO 0 )
                );
    end component OR2;

    component NAND2 is
        port(   Anand, Bnand : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 7 DOWNTO 0 );
                Cnand : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 7 DOWNTO 0 )
                );
    end component NAND2;

    component XOR2 is
        port(   Axor, Bxor : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 7 DOWNTO 0 );
                Cxor : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 7 DOWNTO 0 )
                );
    end component XOR2;

    component MUX4 is
        port(   Cand, Cor, Cnand, Cxor : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 7 DOWNTO 0 );
                OPCODE : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 1 DOWNTO 0 );
                Rez : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 7 DOWNTO 0 )
                );
    end component MUX4;
    -- sfarsit componente
end package componente;

-- pentru AND
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use work.componente.all;
entity AND2 is
    port(   Aand, Band : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 7 DOWNTO 0 );
            Cand : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 7 DOWNTO 0 )
            );
end AND2;
architecture model_and of AND2 is
begin
    Cand(0) <= Aand(0) and Band(0);
    Cand(1) <= Aand(1) and Band(1);
    Cand(2) <= Aand(2) and Band(2);
    Cand(3) <= Aand(3) and Band(3);
    Cand(4) <= Aand(4) and Band(4);
    Cand(5) <= Aand(5) and Band(5);
    Cand(6) <= Aand(6) and Band(6);
    Cand(7) <= Aand(7) and Band(7);
end model_and;

-- pentru OR
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use work.componente.all;
entity OR2 is
    port(   Aor, Bor : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 7 DOWNTO 0 );
            Cor : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 7 DOWNTO 0 )
            );
end OR2;
architecture model_or of OR2 is
begin
    Cor(0) <= Aor(0) or Bor(0);
    Cor(1) <= Aor(1) or Bor(1);
    Cor(2) <= Aor(2) or Bor(2);
    Cor(3) <= Aor(3) or Bor(3);
    Cor(4) <= Aor(4) or Bor(4);
    Cor(5) <= Aor(5) or Bor(5);
    Cor(6) <= Aor(6) or Bor(6);
    Cor(7) <= Aor(7) or Bor(7);
end model_or;

-- pentru NAND
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use work.componente.all;
entity NAND2 is
    port(   Anand, Bnand : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 7 DOWNTO 0 );
            Cnand : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 7 DOWNTO 0 )
            );
end NAND2;
architecture model_nand of NAND2 is
begin
    Cnand(0) <= Anand(0) and Bnand(0);
    Cnand(1) <= Anand(1) and Bnand(1);
    Cnand(2) <= Anand(2) and Bnand(2);
    Cnand(3) <= Anand(3) and Bnand(3);
    Cnand(4) <= Anand(4) and Bnand(4);
    Cnand(5) <= Anand(5) and Bnand(5);
    Cnand(6) <= Anand(6) and Bnand(6);
    Cnand(7) <= Anand(7) and Bnand(7);
end model_nand;

-- pentru XOR
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use work.componente.all;
entity XOR2 is
    port(   Axor, Bxor : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 7 DOWNTO 0 );
            Cxor : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 7 DOWNTO 0 )
            );
end XOR2;
architecture model_xor of XOR2 is
begin
    Cxor(0) <= Axor(0) or Bxor(0);
    Cxor(1) <= Axor(1) or Bxor(1);
    Cxor(2) <= Axor(2) or Bxor(2);
    Cxor(3) <= Axor(3) or Bxor(3);
    Cxor(4) <= Axor(4) or Bxor(4);
    Cxor(5) <= Axor(5) or Bxor(5);
    Cxor(6) <= Axor(6) or Bxor(6);
    Cxor(7) <= Axor(7) or Bxor(7);
end model_xor;

-- 4input MUX
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use work.componente.all;
entity MUX4 is
    port(   Cand, Cor, Cnand, Cxor : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 7 DOWNTO 0 );
            OPCODE : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 1 DOWNTO 0 );
            Rez : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 7 DOWNTO 0 )
            );
end MUX4;
architecture model_mux4 of MUX4 is
begin
    with OPCODE select
        Rez <= Cand when "00",
               Cor when "01",
               Cnand when "10",
               Cxor when "11";
end model_mux4;


library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use work.componente.all;
entity ALU is
    Port ( A : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 7 DOWNTO 0 );
           B : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 7 DOWNTO 0 );
           OPCODE : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 1 DOWNTO 0 );
           C : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 7 DOWNTO 0)
           );
end ALU;

architecture Structural of ALU is

    SIGNAL Cand, Cor, Cnand, Cxor, Rez : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 7 DOWNTO 0 );

    begin

    u0 : AND2 PORT MAP( A, B, Cand );
    u1 : OR2 PORT MAP( A, B, Cor );
    u2 : NAND2 PORT MAP ( A, B, Cnand);
    u3 : XOR2 PORT MAP ( A, B, Cxor);
    u4 : MUX4 PORT MAP ( Cand, Cor, Cnand, Cxor, OPCODE, Rez );
    C <= Rez;
end Structural;
```

Comment: you forgot to change the 8 `and` to `nand` and the 8 `or` to `xor`. And your mux should have a `when others`...